# How can I make margin note notation?

Tags: marginnote

I would like to make margin notes on my document exactly like footnote but on the side. I have used this, it works but there is no notation and the text in the side is big.

```
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1]....\marginnote{This is my note side}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Here is the result :

[image: current]

I want this to do this:

[image: intended]

Comment: Please post only code, which compiles, next time to save a lot of guessing for all of us. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As I read its manual, `marginnote` is a replacement for `marginpar` only, trading new limitations to old ones. It does NOT provide a footnote-like style.

From the other packages listed in the `Notes-category` at ctan, try this one:

- `parnotes`
- seems to require the `autopn`-environment
- use `\parnote{your text here}` to set a note (and its note-counter)
- by default it's placed `at the end of the autopn`-environment (I suppose)
- but you can place it and output it instead in a ... (fanfare) ...
- `\marginpar{}` and put the notes content there immediately: `\marginpar{\parnotes}`

[image: result]

(Right: there is a funny typo in my screenshot, which you may or may not want to re-use ...)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parnotes}% take this one

\begin{document}
 \begin{autopn}
    \lipsum[1] XYZ \parnote{This is my note side} \marginpar{\parnotes} \lipsum[2]\parnote{And an other one goes to \dots}\marginpar{\parnotes}
 \end{autopn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to make a long note at the end of the page, you will not be able to see the whole note

Comment: We like to see code her ;-) // So change your concept. With a certain length, such content may no longer qualify for a margin-note. Depending on their function, alternatives may be text inserts with some graphical features, a section in the abbreviation, redesigned text etc.